# how to properly use rsync from WSL2 to remote ubuntu EC2 server via ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-access, rsync, remote-server

I'm having issues copying a directory from WSL2 to a remote ubuntu EC2 server using rsync.

In WSL2, there is a testfolder in the C drive and I'm calling these commands from the C drive directory from WSL2 ubuntu.  testfolder has a test.txt file inside.

The EC2 is open as `0.0.0.0/0` --- ip isn't an issue.

The remote server ssh key works and I am able to get in and use it.  In the remote server I created a folder `test` from the `~` directory.  Tried using other directories as well just to be sure.

**I have tried the following commands:**

`rsync -rv ./testfolder/ ubuntu@000.00.00.000:.~/test`

**Results**:

```
ssh: connect to host 000.00.00.000 port 22: Connection timed out
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(231) [sender=3.2.7]
```

`rsync -avrzv --rsync-path "sudo rsync" -e "ssh -i ~/path.pem" ./testfolder/ ubuntu@000.00.00.000:~/test`

**Results**:

```
ssh: connect to host 000.00.00.000 port 22: Connection timed out
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(231) [sender=3.2.7]
```

The following is meant for a daemon, not ssh, but attempted anyway.

`rsync -avrzv --rsync-path "sudo rsync" -e "ssh -i ~/path.pem" ./testfolder/ rsync://ubuntu@000.00.00.000:~/test`

**Results**:

```
ssh: connect to host 000.00.00.000 port 22: Connection timed out
rsync: did not see server greeting
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1863) [sender=3.2.7]
```

---

For the port 22 error I did the following based on some articles:

Step 1:

```
systemctl list-unit-files |grep rsync
# this resulted in
rsync.service disabled enabled
```

Step 2:

```
sudo systemctl enable rsync.service
# this resulted in
Synchronizing state of rsync.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable rsync
```

Step 3:

```
sudo systemctl start rsync.service
#this prints nothing but if i run Step 1 again...
systemctl list-unit-files |grep rsync
# this resulted in
rsync.service enabled enabled
```

After doing this the errors persist.

---

I attempted to add `--timeout 9999` but errors persist

---

When running `ping 000.00.00.000` (using remote IP from WSL2 cmd)

I get
`PING 000.00.00.000 (000.00.00.000) 56(84) bytes of data. From 11.11.11.111 icmp_seq=166 Destination Net Unreachable`

---

Checking ports on remote server

```
$ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
systemd-r  305 systemd-resolve   14u  IPv4  16610      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
sshd       546            root    3u  IPv4  17881      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd       546            root    4u  IPv6  17896      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
```

```
$ sudo ss -tulpn | grep LISTEN
tcp   LISTEN 0      128               0.0.0.0:22        0.0.0.0:*    users:(("sshd",pid=546,fd=3))
tcp   LISTEN 0      4096        127.0.0.53%lo:53        0.0.0.0:*    users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=305,fd=14))
tcp   LISTEN 0      128                  [::]:22           [::]:*    users:(("sshd",pid=546,fd=4))
```

```
$ sudo lsof -i:22
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd     546   root    3u  IPv4  xxxxx      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd     546   root    4u  IPv6  xxxxx      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd    2488   root    4u  IPv4  xxxxx      0t0  TCP ip-000-00-00-000.us-east-2.compute.internal:ssh->000.000.000.000.hwccustomers.com:00000 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd    2572 ubuntu    4u  IPv4  xxxxx      0t0  TCP ip-000-00-00-000.us-east-2.compute.internal:ssh->000.000.000.000.hwccustomers.com:00000 (ESTABLISHED)
```

```
$ sudo lsof -i -P -n
COMMAND    PID            USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd-n  303 systemd-network   15u  IPv4  xxxxx      0t0  UDP 172.00.00.00:00
systemd-r  305 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  xxxxx      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.00:53
systemd-r  305 systemd-resolve   14u  IPv4  xxxxx      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.00:53 (LISTEN)
chronyd    359         _chrony    5u  IPv4  xxxxx      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.0:000
chronyd    359         _chrony    6u  IPv6  xxxxx      0t0  UDP [::1]:323
sshd       546            root    3u  IPv4  xxxxx      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd       546            root    4u  IPv6  xxxxx      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd      2488            root    4u  IPv4  xxxxx      0t0  TCP xxx.xx.xx.xxx:22->jjj.jjj.jjj.jjj:60774 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd      2572          ubuntu    4u  IPv4  31800      0t0  TCP xxx.xx.xx.xxx:22->jjj.jjj.jjj.jjj:60774 (ESTABLISHED)
```

^ the xxx.xx.xx.xxx is the remote server ip and the jjj.jjj.jjj.jjj is the ip im on

```
$ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
systemd-r  305 systemd-resolve   14u  IPv4  xxxxx      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.00:00 (LISTEN)
sshd       546            root    3u  IPv4  xxxxx      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd       546            root    4u  IPv6  xxxxx      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
```

It seems like every tutorial makes it so easy to use, they run it and it works.  Unsure what is going on through my computer thats not making it work

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Don't you read the error messages? They all say that the SSH connection is timing out. Most likely there's a firewall blocking the connections.

Comment: Yes, and i read and tried everything i found at the time as you see.  but i found a few posts of people with the same issue using Public IPv4 DNS instead and that worked for me.  unsure what hte problem is with the IP though still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

funny enough, 30 seconds after i posted i tried this and it worked; using the Public IPv4 DNS instead of the IP

```
rsync -avrzv --rsync-path "sudo rsync" -e "ssh -i ~/location.pem" /directory/ ubuntu@ec0-00.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:~/remotedir --progress
```

Figured since it took me so long to figure this out ill keep this here unless mods want to delete!